# How to find 700w rows of data in an Oracle table in a very short time

Tags: java, sql, oracle, multithreading

My idea at the beginning is to use multithreading for batch query, and then the segment is calculated according to the maximum id and minimum id to partition, but unfortunately, my table, id is not continuous... Therefore, I planned to use create_time as the index for subsection search, then group by month and sort by data volume. The month with the largest data volume and the month with the smallest data volume were divided into one group, the month with the second largest data volume and the second smallest data volume were divided into one group, and so on. Each thread was responsible for one group, so that the data volume could be evenly distributed. It's about 25w for a group, but it still doesn't meet the manager's needs. He still asked me to use ids for grouping. He said that although the table id was not contiguous, the library id was contiguous, generated using hibernate's autoincrement sequence. But I looked at the table and the difference between the maximum id and the minimum id was more than 3 billion, and the data was only about 7 million. Could you please tell me if there is a better solution, or what should I do according to my manager's idea?

I want to complete this query in less time

Comment: Please define: 'very', 'sort', 'very sort time'.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to be helpful. We would need to see the (simplest) query you are using to pull data that meets your business needs, and how long it's taking you now, and whether you are timining based on the first row returned or all rows returned. Also, what does "700w" mean? I can tell you right now that indexing is not the right approach, but I can't advise you further until we get some specifics. We can't make much of a paragraph using language understandable only in your environment.

Answer (score 2):

You are not going to get more performance by parallelising your client application and throwing more queries at the database; if anything that is going to degrade performance as the database will have more to deal with and everything is going to get bottlenecked at the database's I/O when it reads the table from disk.

You can consider partitioning the table (and storing each partition on a different physical drive) and then you could use multiple queries where each query returns data from a different partition and you can actually take advantage of parallel I/O.